# Doubt regarding ERC20 Token exchange restriction

Tags: erc-20, wallet-transfer, decentralized-exchange

I just have one question. I'm creating an ERC20 token but I want to restrict the exchange of these tokens to only my platform. At the same time, I also want to support all the wallets out there for holding these tokens, hence going with ERC20. Is this type of behavior possible?

Comment: Probably the closest thing you can do is to charge a fee in every transaction unless it is done through your exchange.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing i can think of that is to require any `_transfer` to come from or be directed to your exchange's router. That would disable transfers between EOAs as well though, or use in any other contract.